# Copying a DB or tables from a local Postgres database to Heroku

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, heroku

I'm almost a novice with databases.
I created a PostgreSQL database with the python programming language. 
I am pleased to note that the database was created as I wished. I could easily verify it from pgAdmin 4, the database administrator installed locally. 
But now, since it is ready to be used, I would like to upload it to Heroku in order to work with it inside my web application. 

I followed the various steps slavishly on the [site of Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql), but I can not complete the various steps, especially at the following command:

```
set DATABASE_URL=postgres://$(whoami)
```

I wonder if it's an operating system problem, in the sense that the steps listed on the Heroku site could be os-agnostic and not addressed to Windows, the system I'm working on. I also believe that some commands are directed to connect the database that is located locally, not to migrate on the domain of Heroku.

Comment: It might help to talk about the specific steps you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a dump of the db under Windows as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44159699/470530). This will be a human readable text file - worth a look to get a feel for what's going on "under the hood", i.e. in the background!

Then, ftp that file (as text) over to the Heroku box (Linux I presume) and do a restore from the dump as outlined [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE).

```
psql dbname < infile
```

You may have to create an empty schema - can't remember.

Then use psql to connect to your new db.

p.s. a word to the wise - if you're going to be using Python, Heroku and PostgreSQL, then you should be using a Linux box as your main machine - all three are Linux "natives" rather than Windows. Try it out - you'll wonder how you ever did things any other way!

Comment: After executing the first instruction you suggested, a SQL file was generated. Proud of this I tried to shoot him on heroku, but without success. After a full day of attempts, I found that the reason was that the company's connection does not allow access to the databases on Heroku, and therefore the problem was insurmountable, using the company's connection. So as soon as I made an attempt with another connection, everything worked wonderfully! Instead of continuing with your tutorial though, I used the following command to upload the sql file to Heroku `heroku pg:psql --app myapp < file.sql`

Comment: Did you try SFTP using a tool like Putty?

Comment: I'm not very practical with putty. But I assume it can be very cumbersome as a matter. Fortunately, this solution came to mind. Seeing that on the web there was often a reference to the firewall regarding the postgreSQL-Heroku question, the company filters came into my mind and in fact, after a few seconds, with another connection, everything worked. :)